Database does not exist docker image Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3D000: database "CatalogDb" does not exist
I am trying to connect to postgres database running on docker container from visual studio, I am sure the DB exists and here is the logs:
docker ps:
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
a84a2dabf8a6   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   catalogdb

My connection string:
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=CatalogDb;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Include Error Detail=true;"
  }

inside docker container:
postgres=# \l
                                                      List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Locale Provider |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | ICU Rules |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------
 CatalogDb | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            |           |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            |           |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            |           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                 |            |            |            |           | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            |           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                 |            |            |            |           | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)


docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.4'

services:    
  catalogdb:
    image: postgres

volumes:
  postgres_catalog:
  

and override.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    environment:
       - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
       - POSTGRES_DB=CatalogDb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_catalog:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    

the error:
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3D000: database "CatalogDb" does not exist
I try to connect postgresql Db from visual studio to existing Database but got database does not exist error. How can I connect to psql db running on docker container from visual studio.
SOLVED:
Just changed ports in appsettings.json to 5433 and also  in docker compose file 5433:5432. It was just the case 5432 is being used I guess.

The solution above worked.  For anyone else who has the same issue, please make sure you rerun docker-compose after you change the port.  It didn't work at first, but after I rerun docker-compose, the problem is resolved.
